# Populating postgres db via terminal with sql file

Tags: postgresql, terminal, stdin, tty

Hey I'm using Windows 10 and trying to import data into a postgresql database.
When running

`cat my_tables.sql | my_first_db`

I get an error saying that `stdin is not a tty` and nothing gets added to the database. I looked here in the forum and also didn't find anything googling. Can you help please?

Comment: Why not use `psql -U ... -d ... -f my_tables.sql`?

Comment: You can also run your script after logging into PostgreSQL from command line (using psql) and then run `\i script.sql`

Comment: this seems to work, I get the message that tables are created, but when logging into postgres loading the db I get an error that the columns don't exist. I'll see if I can find what's wrong. The command `psql -U ... -d ... -f my_tables.sql` seems to work

Comment: Ok, it's working now  - thank you! I couldn't load the table because I had DROP TABLE <column_name>; at the end of the file. When I uncomment those lines it does load the db!